# iOS5 TabBar Fonts and Color

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbar, ios5

I have customized the TabBar appearance such

```
UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-bar-bg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"activetab.png"]];
```

How do I define the custom fonts and the selected and unselected text colors?

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8412083/886407

Comment: Oh wicked! I tried searching, clearly not hard enough! Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"font" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
      nil] 
                                             forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: how to set edgeinsets for title?

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala setTitlePositionAdjustment:(UIOffset)adjustment

Answer (score 13):

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Semibold" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
      nil] 
                                             forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Semibold" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
      nil] 
                                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is working for me.

But I think most people should change the 
`forState:UIControlStateHighlighted` to `forstate:UIControlStateSelected`