# Changing Text Color of Unselected UITabBarItems

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboard, uitabbaritem

Here's what I've tried:

I've tried the following in the **parent view controller**:

```
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                               nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I've tried the following in the **application delegate**:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] 
 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                         nil]
 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I've even tried changing `UIControlStateNormal` to any of the other available constants. The only one that changes anything is `UIControlStateHighlighted` which changes the color of the highlighted tab. Is this a bug in the API or is there something I'm missing?

Key things to note:

- I'm using storyboarding
- I have a `UITabBarController` where each tab has an embedded `UINavigationController` (pretty standard setup)
- I've tried embedding the first code snippet into both the `UINavigationController` subclass as well as the root `UIViewController` subclass that is inside the `UINavigationController`. No luck there either.

Comment: what do you want to change the text color to? Doesn't it make the unselected ones dark gray and the highlighted one a white-gray by default?

Comment: Yes. I'm wanting to change the unselected grey text to white.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe Apple wants all tab bars to be like that in their human interface guidelines, maybe not that color but the unselected ones have to be a different color than the selected one. So it should be possible and we can continue to find a solution, but if you want to make them all the same regardless of the currently selected one you're S.O.L

Comment: I really was not going to make them all white for both states, I just wanted to know how to change it and I was trying white as a sample color.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284433/ios5-tabbar-fonts-and-color, let me know if you want me to make it an answer

Comment: In my searching prior to posting this question, I tried that one and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412010/how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-uitabbaritem-in-ios-5/8412083#8412083. Niether of them work.

Comment: Are you implementing UITabBarControllerDelegate or UITabBarDelegate in the controller you are trying to change the colors from?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13861/discussion-between-jesse-bunch-and-user1458968)