# How to use a custom font in iOS tab bar

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm using the font awesome resource for the UI of my iPhone application :
[FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

I have used it within my app screens like follows :

```
Phone.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:40];
Phone.text = [NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-phone"];
```

But now I want to use it in the tab bar items of my tab bar controller i.e I want to set the icons of the tab bar to font awesome elements. How can this be done?

Comment: is this solved already?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per: [How to change the Color of text in UITabBarItem in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412010/how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-uitabbaritem-in-ios-5)

It looks like the solution may be sending the message to the appearance proxy, instead of one item:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                    NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f]
                                                    } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

here is some more reference

[how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-uitabbaritem-in-ios-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412010/how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-uitabbaritem-in-ios-5)

[ios5-tabbar-fonts-and-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284433/ios5-tabbar-fonts-and-color)

Answer (score 9):

Swift version:

```
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
            [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Ubuntu", size:11)!, 
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(rgb: 0x929292)], 
            forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: As of 6.1 you must unwrap the font. Just put ! after your the font init

Comment: Thanks and yes it's started from `Swift 1.2`. Edited.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Latio-Regular", size:14)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

This is an example how it works with Swift 4:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Renner-it-Book", size: 10)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to change the font using the accepted answer. This is what I used later in my

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

method of AppDelegate:

```
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    [tabBarItem1 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17 weight:UIFontWeightBold], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [tabBarItem2 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17 weight:UIFontWeightBold], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [tabBarItem1 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17 weight:UIFontWeightBold], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [tabBarItem2 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17 weight:UIFontWeightBold], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

More information here: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-how-to-customize-tab-bar-background-appearance/

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: TAB_BAR_TEXT_NORMAL_COLOR, NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:CUSTOM_FONT_NAME size:TAB_BAR_FONT_SIZE]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:CUSTOM_FONT_NAME size:TAB_BAR_FONT_SIZE]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 2):

Since in iOS7 `UITextAttributeFont` is deprecated, use **`NSFontAttributeName`**

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"your_font_name" size:20.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

use this it works perfectly...

```
UIView *iv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,230.0,80.0)];
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 230, 80)];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu" size:18.0f];
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu Store Found",(unsigned long)arrOfferList.count];
[iv addSubview:lbl];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.titleView = iv;
```