# How to set Font Of tabbar title in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, set, tabbar

I want to set font of `tabBar` title as ubuntu but I can't set that.

I write below code for that:

```
    self.tabBarController.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = 
      @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], 
      NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu" size:9.0f]};
```

Comment: check the font is added correctly or not else try this add another font and check once

Comment: yes font added correctly

Answer (score 1):

Objective C Code-

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"your_font_name" size:20.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Swift Code-

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
        [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"your_font_name", size:11)!, 
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(rgb: 0x929292)], 
        forState: .Normal)
```

For more refrence-
[iOS5 TabBar Fonts and Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284433/ios5-tabbar-fonts-and-color)

Answer (score 1):

i found one solution..
first i create custom label and after that i change font of that....

```
UIView *iv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,230.0,80.0)];
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 230, 80)];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu" size:18.0f];
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu Store Found",(unsigned long)arrOfferList.count];
[iv addSubview:lbl];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.titleView = iv;
```