# Changing font in UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I have this code and it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}
```

BTW that's not the only thing in my viewDidLoad but I just wanted to show you guys thats where I put it.

Comment: Can you share what version of iOS you are targeting? This feature is new to iOS 5.

Comment: @ctrahey I am targeting iOS 5.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As per: [How to change the Color of text in UITabBarItem in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412010/how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-uitabbaritem-in-ios-5)

It looks like the solution may be sending the message to the appearance proxy, instead of one item:

**(Deprecated in iOS 7.0+)**

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**For iOS 7.0+ use:**

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: change forstate:UIControlStateNormal

Comment: Not explicitly mentioned here. You can put this code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in the app delegate to set it for the app

Comment: That worked for me in swift:    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 20.0)] as [NSObject : AnyObject!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

Comment: NSFontAttributeName for iOS7+, and UITextAttributeFont for iOS6-

Comment: `@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f]}` for 2015.

Comment: change different font for **Selected** state is no effect

Comment: @BeyondChao it might be worth asking a fresh question (or searching differently) as this answer is now over 6 years old! Good luck!

Answer (score 18):

Swift way, for lazies:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)], forState: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)], forState: .selected)
```

Comment: This doesn't change the font for me for `.selected` state.

Comment: @AbbasAngouti for changing font is selected state you should use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529912/1980246

Comment: Update, as of iOS 15, if the UITabBar uses UITabBarItemAppearance(), it will override any fonts set in the UITabBarItem.appearance() setting

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4.1 and custom font**

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Medium", size: 11)], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Medium", size: 11)], for: .selected)
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 10)!], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

Lets say you have a class that inherits `UITabBarController` like below:

```
final class YourTabBarController: UITabBarController { .. }
```

Define 2 types of attribute in this `YourTabBarController`:

```
let normalTabBarAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .font: NotSelectedFont,
    .foregroundColor: NotSelectedColor
]
let selectedTabBarAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .font: SelectedFont,
    .foregroundColor: SelectedColor
]
```

And you have a `ViewController` named `YourViewController` that contains the `TabBar` and inherits `UIViewController` like below:

```
final class YourViewController: UIViewController {...}
```

**iOS 15.0 or later version**

Define a method in `YourViewController`:

```
private func setTabBarAttributes() {
    guard let yourTabBarController = tabBarController as? YourTabBarController else {
        return
    }
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = yourTabBarController.normalTabBarAttributes
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = yourTabBarController.selectedTabBarAttributes
    yourTabBarController.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    yourTabBarController.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Form `override func viewDidLoad()` method of `YourViewController` call that method:

```
setTabBarAttributes()
```

**previous versions of iOS 15.0**

In `YourTabBarController` you can define a method :

```
private func updateTabBarAttributes() {
    guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else { return }
    for viewController in viewControllers {
        if viewController == selectedViewController {
            viewController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedTabBarAttributes, for: .normal)
        } else {
            viewController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTabBarAttributes, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Now use the method like below:

```
override var selectedIndex: Int {
    didSet {
        updateTabBarAttributes()
    }
}

override var selectedViewController: UIViewController? {
    didSet {
        updateTabBarAttributes()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.tabbar], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I added the code in viewDidLoad() then I was never able to change the font when the tabbar was selected.

This is a great article that explains how to do it with more details: [HolySwift Article](https://holyswift.app/how-to-change-tab-bar-item-font-when-selected-in-swift)

In a nutshell, you need to add the following code in your tabbar controller:

```
override var selectedIndex: Int { 
    didSet {
        guard let selectedViewController = viewControllers?[selectedIndex] else {
            return
        }
        selectedViewController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)], for: .normal) 
    }
}
```

And this:

```
override var selectedViewController: UIViewController? { 
    didSet {

        guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else {
            return
        }

        for viewController in viewControllers {
            if viewController == selectedViewController {
                viewController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)], for: .normal)
            } else {
                viewController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)], for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: This will work with custom fonts as well.