# Customizing appearance of tabBarItems in a TabBArController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

In my application, I am using a `UITabBarController`. However, i need to customise the appearance of my `UITabBarItems`.

At present, my screen looks like this:

[image]

I would like to increase the distance between the tabs, and the middle tab has bigger text, due to which the tab looks very crowded. Also, i would like to add a separator between the tabs.

Here's the code:

```
customerCareNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:custCareVC];
    customerCareNavController.title = @"Inquiry";

    purchaseOrderNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:POController];
    purchaseOrderNavController.title = @"Purchase Order";

    accAndContactsNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:accAndContactsController];
    accAndContactsNavController.title = @"Accounts And Contacts";

    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:customerCareNavController,accAndContactsNavController,purchaseOrderNavController, nil];

[(UITabBarItem*)[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Customer_Service.png"]];


        [(UITabBarItem*)[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Acc_Cont.png"]];


        [(UITabBarItem*)[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PO.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set tabBarItem such like

```
UITabBarItem* ClientSupportTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
[ClientSupportTabBarItem  setFinishedSelectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"btnTabItem-active.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"btnTabItemNormal.png"]];
ClientSupportTabBarItem.title = @"Inquiry";
[customerCareNavController setTabBarItem: ClientSupportTabBarItem];
```

Comment: how to change the font size and font family of the title??? and how to add separator in the tabs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069437/changing-font-in-uitabbaritem and to add separator in the tabs, i thinks your meed to create image of UITabBarItem..

Comment: For set font also check ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576592/changing-font-size-of-tabbaritem