# Change font for selected UITabBarItem with objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uifont

I would like to change the font of a selected UITabBarItem to bold if it is selected. I have done following to set image and text to white and I also set the font, but only the color changes on selecting UITabBarItem, not the font.

```
// Normal font       
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:MY_LIGHT_FONT, NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor grayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Selected font
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:MY_BOLD_FONT, NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

The selected font does not change anything.

[image]

The calendar text should be bold.

Comment: check this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/41082581/4831524

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069437/changing-font-in-uitabbaritem

Comment: @liangju For UIStateNormal my solution already works, but not selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TimurBernikowich mentioned, font parameter **doesn't work for selected state** on iOS11.

Comment: any solution for iOS11 ?

Comment: @GonzoOin Sadly, Apple did not changed this with iOS 11

Comment: It's sad. I've end up by reseting tab bar items by overriding didSelectItem method

Answer (score 1):

```
  [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:MONSREGULAR size:10.0f],
                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName :[UIColor colorWithRed:0.004 green:0.820 blue:0.369 alpha:1.00];
                                                        } forState:UIControlStateSelected];


    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:MONSREGULAR size:10.0f],
                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName :[UIColor darkgraycolor];
                                                        } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Font parameter doesn't work for selected state on iOS11.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Normal font       
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:MY_LIGHT_FONT, NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor grayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Selected font
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:MY_BOLD_FONT, NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

**tried this:**

```
    // Normal font
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"your-font" size:10.f],  NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   //selected state
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"your-font bold" size:10.f], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: That's the same like my solution.