# How to change the [more] button text color in UITabBar?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412010/how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-uitabbaritem-in-ios-5/8412083#8412083) change the bar items text color to white,but I have 6 tabbar items,I can't get the system button [more] item and change the text color.

How to change this [more] button text color to white?
thx.

[image: look the more button]

my code:

```
for (UITabBarItem* item in self.tabBar.items)
{
    NSLog(@"title:%@",item.title); // only get my items
    [item setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:11.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                  [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                  [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                  nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: did you use [UITabBarItem appearance] or smth. else?

Comment: yes,`tabBar.items` i only get my items,can not get the system `more` tabbaritem,so I can not use `setTitleTextAttributes` on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried this , it's work for me :

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                             [UIColor yellowColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                             [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                             [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                             nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or replace self.myTabBar with [UITabBarItem appearance]

Comment: nice person,BTW,i have another question about this,How to change the icons color to white? now tabbar tint color is blue,but i want a different color for the image icon.is tabbar can make it?