# Is there any way to set an image title or attributed string for tab bar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitabbar, nsattributedstring

It seems that there is no way to actually set an image for the tab bar title.

Furthermore, can I change the title's font or basically use an attributed string as a tab bar title?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want a tab bar where each tab has two (stacked) images (or alternatively, an image and attributed string)?

Comment: @Doc exactly, either two (stacked) images or an image and an attributed string.

Comment: [This other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412010/how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-uitabbaritem-in-ios-5) explains how to set the text attributes for a uitabbaritem.  As far as setting an image instead, I don't think that it's possible - you may need to make a custom control to do that.

Comment: @Doc thanks, i will look into that, although it is for iOS 5.

Comment: The setTitleTextAttributes:forState: was added in iOS 5.  It's usable in all versions since then.

Comment: @Doc cool, i will try that once i get home.

Comment: @David Liu Did you get any solution yet?